# Как перегрузить оператор умножения для шаблонного класса с разными параметрами?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Требуется, чтобы перегруженный оператор умножал x и y, когда в шаблонный класс передаётся класс Complex. Когда передаётся Polar, то только x должен умножаться. Но компилятор ругается на перегрузку

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex{
public:

    double x,y;
    static Complex rand_c(){
        Complex c;
        cin>>c.x;
        cin>>c.y;
        return c;
    }
    void to_str(char* bufer){
        sprintf(bufer, "%2lf %2lf", x, y);
    }
};
class Polar{
public:
    double x;
    int y;
    static Polar rand_c(){
        Polar c;
        cin>>c.x;
        cin>>c.y;
        return c;
    }
    void to_str(char* bufer){
        sprintf(bufer, "%2lf %d", x, y);
    }
};
template <typename T>
class Matrix{
public:
    int n,i,j,m;
    T**arr;
    Matrix(int n,int m){
        this->n=n;
        this->m=m;
        arr=new T* [n];
        for (i=0; i<n; i++){
            arr[i]=new T[m];
        }       
}
    void Zap(){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
                arr[i][j]=T::rand_c();
            }
        }
    }

    friend Matrix<Complex> operator *(Matrix<Complex>& a, int& u){
        for(int i=0;i<a.n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<a.m;j++){
                a.arr[i][j].x=a.arr[i][j].x*u;
                a.arr[i][j].y=a.arr[i][j].y*u;
            }
            
        }
        return a;
    }
    
    friend Matrix<Polar> operator *(Matrix<Polar>& b, int& v){
        for(int i=0;i<b.n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<b.m;j++){
                b.arr[i][j].x=b.arr[i][j].x*v;
            }
            
        }
        return b;
    }
    Matrix operator=(const Matrix<T>& b){
        for(int i=0;i<b.n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<b.m;j++){
                arr[i][j].x=b.arr[i][j].x;
                arr[i][j].y=b.arr[i][j].y;
            }
            
        }
        return *this;
    }
    void print(){
        char* bufer=new char[100];
        cout<<"Matrix"<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
                arr[i][j].to_str(bufer);
                printf("%s\t",bufer);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n,m,flag,v=3;
    cin>>flag;
    cin>>n>>m;
    if(flag==1){
        Matrix<Complex> a(n,m);
        Matrix<Complex> b(n,m);
        b.Zap();
        a=b*v;
        a.print();
    }
    else{
        Matrix<Polar> a(n,m);
        Matrix<Polar> b(n,m);
        b.Zap();
        a=b*v;
        a.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы оставьте в классе только объявление — ну, там, `friend Matrix<Complex> operator *(Matrix<Complex>& a, int& u);`, а определение вынесите наружу, вне класса...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае класс матрицы абсолютно не должен знать, как именно там умножаются элементы. Это не его дело. Поэтому, сделаем так

Объявим операторы умножения Complex и Polar  на число

```
Complex operator*(Complex c, int u)
{
    return {c.x*u, c.y*u};
}

Polar operator*(Polar c, int u)
{
    return {c.x*u, c.y};
}
```

Эти функции просты и понятно, что ожидать от них. И здесь можно понять, что у Polar `x` должна называться `r`.

И функция умножения матрицы на число теперь стает простой и очевидной

```
friend Matrix operator *(Matrix& a, int u){
    for(int i=0;i<a.n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a.m;j++){
            a.arr[i][j] = a.arr[i][j] * u;
        } 
    }
    return a;
}
```

Большой плюс такого подхода, что если Ваша матрица хранит к примеру `double`, то умножение на число сразу заработает. А если там будет какой то пользовательский тип, то всегда можно дописать оператор умножения.

(я сделал одно маленькое изменение параметр `int u` передается по значению - это же простой тип. Передавая по ссылке сразу убрали возможность умножить просто на число, нужно только через переменную.)

Но у этой функции есть ещё одна проблема - она модифицирует исходный массив, а потом его по копии возвращает. Ух... лучше пусть она не модифицирует его.

Думаю, что вот в таком виде

```
friend Matrix operator *(const Matrix& a, int u){
    Matrix t{a};
    for(int i=0;i<t.n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<t.m;j++){
            t.arr[i][j] = t.arr[i][j] * u;
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

оно сильно-сильно лучше.

Comment: А как связаны перегрузка оператора в классах и в шаблонном классе?

Comment: И что передаётся в фигурных скобках t{a}?

Comment: фигурные скобки - это новый (ну да, десять лет как) синтаксис. Можно написать и `Matrix t(a);` (что бы просто скопировать матрицу с a в t. По первому вопросу - когда коду умножения матрицы на числу нужно будет умножить элемент на число, то просто поищет подходящую функцию. а ее мы предоставили:)